# Getting Chrome Browser in java Applications

Tags: java, google-chrome, chromium, chromium-embedded, embedded-browser

Is there a way to get the Chrome browser inside of java applications similar to the way Awesomium works in C++ and C# applications?

Comment: i finally succeed to update the old code (11/2010) with the last CEF1 06/2013, last code can be retrived here
[CefJavaWrapper](http://code.google.com/p/cefjavawrapper/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is currently no way getting the UI portion into a Java. You should consider just using barebone WebKit + V8 with many JNI calls. You could consider writing a JNA wrapper around those.

To make your JNA easier, you can wrap [Chromium Embedded Framework](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/)

Comment: You mean by barebone just the portion of the browser that displays the web page? Cause that's all I want.

Comment: Java (Sun) was porting WebKit to Java Swing as JWebPane, but ever since Oracle bought Sun, we never heard any updates. And that was around 2+ years ago. If your experienced in JNA, this could be done, Chromium Web Pane is all about v8 + WebKit. CEF (the link I mentioned above) have done the abstractions for you and all you do i s hook it up to your JNA interface.

Comment: I have very little Java experience, the most being some scripts written for a Runescape bot, RSBot. However, I think I may be able to figure out what I need with what you've given me. Thanks!

Comment: Can you give me the example. or the steps involved to embed chrome browser in java application..I want to play flash vedios and live streaming videos in that application.....

Answer (score 8):

There's a [Java Wrapper for the Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF)](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/java-cef).

Answer (score 2):

Try [javacef](https://code.google.com/p/javacef/). This is open source project. This project can embed Chromium browser in Java SWT with multitab browser support, cookies manipulation, tab settings, printing, back, forward, refresh buttons and enhanced file download. This project is based on Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF).